# C# program that replaces even numbers with the word even

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program that replaces even numbers with the word "EVEN". So far, I have:

```
List<int> num = new List<int>();
for (int num1 = 0; num < 101; num++)
{
  num.add(num1)
}

foreach(int n in num1)
{
  if (n/3)
  {
     num.Replace("EVEN")
  }
}
```

Is this close or am I far off?

Comment: Well, it's about as far away from being well-typed as you can get in such a small task ;)

Comment: You're replacing numbers divisible by 3. Totally not going to work. Consider calculating the remainder of something divided by 2.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram is n/3 really a condition at all?

Comment: This should not compile.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, I notice your `foreach(int n in num1)` should be `foreach(int n in num)`. You also can't add strings to a `List<int>`. By the way, is this homework? Homework is allowed, but it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why you are trying to do this, but this should work..:

```
var num = new List<string>();
for (int n = 0; n < 101; n++)
{
   num.Add(n % 2 == 0 ? "EVEN" : n.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
   string value = (i % 2 == 0) ? "EVEN" : i.ToString();
   list.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: we arrived at **almost** the same solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

In one line:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => (i % 2 == 0) ? "EVEN" : i.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: I like it, but I question the value in doing it in one line. At least add new lines for readability.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 100)` was what I was trying to remember. This is probably way above the questioner's level right now, though.

Comment: +1: Looks like homework question to me :) - so one line answer with as many advanced concepts possible is better. And it useful to learn LINQ even if it is not homework.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions have been provided for constructing a list of strings where each element of the list will be the number if it's odd or "EVEN" if it's even.

If, for some reason, you actually need to take an existing list of `int` and perform such a replacement, make sure you understand a fundamental problem: You can't insert the `string` "EVEN" into a strongly-typed list of `int`.

If you do start with a `List<int>`, you'll have to iterate over it and insert the results into a new `List<string>`, replacing even numbers with "EVEN" as per @CMP or @Can Gencer's answers.

Comment: If that is really what he wants to do he could use a list of object and lose the strong typing, but I don't think any of us would recommend that solution to somebody new to the language.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that solution to somebody, full stop. I can't imagine a non-homework situation in which you'd prefer a mixed list of ints and strings over some other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
.Select(n => (n % 2) == 0 ? "EVEN" : n.ToString())
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of numbers probably should be string if you want to replace with "even".

```
        List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
        numbers.Add("1");
        numbers.Add("2");
        numbers.Add("3");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            int n = 0;
            bool success = int.TryParse(numbers[i], out n);

            if (success && n % 2 == 0)
            {
                numbers[i] = "Even";
            }
        }

        //Output Test Results
        foreach (string number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
```